# How to get socket.io.js file from server using sails.js

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to make a angularjs application, independent from a node.js server that is running sailsjs.

I would like to use socket.io for this application and apparently I need to get the socket.io.js file from the server.

In my client I load the js file in my Index.html file using:

```
<script src="http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

However sails do not deliver the file because of a handshake error.

Is there anyway to get the file from the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the node.js server, why don't you just copy the socket.io.js file to the web server, and fetch it from there?

Comment: Yeah, I finally opted for that solution. I was misunderstanding how socket.io-client was working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The handshake error is explained here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/wiki/sockets#500-error-handshake-error-returned-from-socketio-request

You do not have a session with the server so when socket.io.js is included, there is no session cookie for it to use and the handshake fails. You need to make a successful request to the server beforehand that opens a session. This would need to be a CORS request since your server and their server are on different domains. CORS would need to be enabled on the server side using the method explained here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/config.routes.md#cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is the Javascript Client SDK to communicate with Sails via sockets.

Here is the official project on github: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js